# Assign all distinct items from one column of IEnumerable to SelectList

Tags: c#, linq

I have an IEnumerable that contains multiple "columns" of data. I want to take all of the distinct values from one column only and assign that to a SelectList.

I've tried using LINQ expressions like SelectMany, Select, and Distinct, but I'm not very versed in LINQ and I'm just kind of stabbing in the dark. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Can you provide some code? What is your enumerable looks like, what are columns, some sample of data

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this with a combination of Select and Distinct.

First, use Select to select the value you want. Next, use Distinct to take only distinct values.

For simplicity, these can be chained like this:

```
var selectListData = srcEnumerable.Select(x => x.DesiredField).Distinct();
```

Answer (score 1):

As Jim's Answer you can use select and distinct. But you can do it by using [**morelinq (Extensions to LINQ to Objects)**](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) at one call as below

```
var list1 = products.DistinctBy(x=> x.Code);
```